# Can't launch my flutter app with VScode and Android Studio Emulator

Tags: flutter

I can't launch my flutter app, this is the message I get when I try to run with debbug and without debbug mode:

Your launch config references a program that does not exist. If you have problems launching, check the "program" field in your ".vscode/launch.json" file.

My .json file by default:

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Dart",
      "program": "lib/main.dart",
      "request": "launch",
      "type": "dart"
    }
  ]
```

I run flutter doctor:

```
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[√] VS Code (version 1.46.1)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

And accepted all the licenses.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

**Consider these two**:

---

**1.** Make sure that you opened the root of the project, **not a folder higher**. So that `.vscode` folder will be created on the same level as `lib` folder.

[image: Screen of vscode]

---

**2.** Check that `lib/main.dart` exists. If your `main` function is different, edit the `launch.json` file and change the program.

[image: Screen of vscode]

---

Answer (score 1):

delete your launch.json file and then open your debug menu and click on create a launch.json file

[image]

From the dropdown, select dart and Flutter and run the app again

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if you are facing this problem kindly check the following steps
Try to give a perfect path to your main.dart file in flutter app from launch.json file
eg.

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Dart",
      "program": "shop_app/lib/main.dart",
      "request": "launch",
      "type": "dart"
    }
  ]
}
```

if it does not work then from the terminal type

1. **flutter clean**
2. **flutter run**

Answer (score 1):

Adding the correct root folder as cwd to the launch config fixed it for me.

```
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Flutter",
            "type": "dart",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "lib/main.dart",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
```

Pretty sure this was not the answer when the question was asked, but I got the same error message apparently after a recent update of the flutter extension in VS Code.
It looks like they changed how the working directory is deduced if not specified: https://dartcode.org/releases/v3-50/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the configurations program path is the same path of your main.dart or wherever your main method is.

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

[image: Make sure the configurations program path is the same]

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Dart & Flutter",
        "request": "launch",
        "type": "dart",
        "program": "lib/main.dart"
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Better add the complete path and it worked for me. This has occurred since I have moved my main. dart file from lib to new folder widgets. once I gave the complete path it worked.

```
"configurations": [

    {
        "name": "exp_app",
        "request": "launch",
        "type": "dart",
        "program": "E:\\FLUTTER\\exp_app\\lib\\widgets\\main.dart"
    }
]
```